# Relations and Equivalence Sequences

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

A relation is defined on the set $A=\{a + b\sqrt{2} \; : \; a, b \in \mathbb{Q} \text{ and } a + b\sqrt{2} \neq 0\}$ by $xRy$ if $x/y$ is in $\mathbb{Q}$.
Show that $R$ is an equivalence relation and determine the distinct equivalence classes.

I showed that $R$ is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive already, and so I know that $R$ is an equivalence relation. 
My issue is finding the equivalence classes. Since $x,y$ are coming from set $A$ but set $A$ uses $a,b$ which come from $\mathbb{Q}$, how do I define the equivalence classes?

I tried this: 
$[1] = \{x \in A \; : \; xR1\} = \{x \in A \; : \; x \in \mathbb{Q}\} = \{a + b\sqrt{2} \; : \; a \in \mathbb{Q}, b=0\}$.

Is that the correct way to define it?

Comment: By "rad(2)" do you mean $\sqrt{2}$?  You write that as $\backslash\text{sqrt}\{2\}$.

Comment: Yes sorry I'm not too good with the symbols.

Comment: Put math stuff between dollar signs like $\$\backslash\text{sqrt}\{2\}\$$.

Comment: You might want to see this to gain more understanding about equivalence classes http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1232413/equivalence-classes-points-on-the-plane/1232433#1232433

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is one equivalence class for each rational $r\in\mathbb Q$.  That's because $a+b\sqrt{2}$ is equivalent to $r+\sqrt{2}$ where $r=a/b$.  Now just show $r+\sqrt{2}$ is equivalent to $s+\sqrt{2}$ iff $r=s$.